# Optimising regex for matching text in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7, regex-negation, regex-group

I am learning regex and came across a use case in which there was a very large pdf and my aim was to filter out content from the pdf based on following:

1. Starting delimiter will be either "incoming message" or "outgoing message"
2. Followed by starting delimiter, there will be text which may contain my keyword. If the text contain the keyword then i would extract the message
3. I am presuming ending delimiter to be same i.e. "incoming message" or "outgoing message"

I have made following regex: 
`((?:(?!((\sincoming|outgoing)\smessage)).)*keyword.*?)((incoming|outgoing)\smessage)`
The regex is working perfectly for me for small documents say for 1000pages of pdf but it hangs for say 13000 pages of document(Code was running for more than 12hrs in this case).
I am extracting group(1) only from the regex result. I suspect the large number of groups which i have made are causing it to slow down and run matches iteratively. However i would appreciate if anyone can guide on how to go about building such regex and any efficient alternate which will yield result in a decent timeframe. I am using python 2.7 for my script.

Sample text can be:

Incoming message
Incoming message
Incoming message
keyword
abctext
keyword
Incoming message
Incoming message
gsgsfvhvhgh
gfvgvhhhjjbn
765568856866

Incoming message
outgoing message
Incoming message
91981966802866
keyword
other text
Dhai
20-12-2017 15:29:47
Text
Incoming message

The output should be:

1. match1:incoming message keyword abctext keyword
2. match2: incoming message 91981966802866
   keyword
   other text
   Dhai
   20-12-2017 15:29:47
   Text

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/Phrdny/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following (group 0 match):

[`(?:incoming|outgoing)\smessage(?:(?!(?:incoming|outgoing)\smessage).)*keyword.*?(?=(?:incoming|outgoing)\smessage)`](https://regex101.com/r/PLk9Rx/2)

shows 1868 steps whereas original does 20020 steps, instead of

[`((?:(?!((\sincoming|outgoing)\smessage)).)*keyword.*?)((incoming|outgoing)\smessage)`](https://regex101.com/r/PLk9Rx/1)

starting with an exact match instead of a negative lookahead reduces the backtracking.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts! Guess this will optimise the results alot. @Wiktor: Thanks alot for the help.